# how to make class variable callable from another class in python

Tags: python, python-sockets

So i am making a socket server in python and i want to use classes. The problem is that when calling setup.com_socket.recv() variable, the result can be printed, but it cannot be called. Problem is in verify.py. Here is the code:

```
server.py:



import socket
import threading
from verify import Verify
from setup import Setup


verify = Verify()#start the classes for use
setup = Setup()

setup.make_server()
verify.verify()


setup.py:



import socket

class Setup:
    def __init__(self):
        self.server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.client_list: list = []
        self.com_socket = ""
        self.addr: int = 0
        self.current_id: int = 0


    def make_server(self):

        self.server.bind(('localhost', 9999))

        self.server.listen()
        print("listening to connections")

        self.com_socket, self.addr = self.server.accept()
        self.client_list.append(self.com_socket)

        with open('current_id.txt', 'r') as f:
            self.current_id = int(f.readlines()[0].rstrip())
            self.com_socket.send(str(self.current_id).encode('utf-8'))

        with open('current_id.txt', 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(self.current_id+1))


        return True




verify.py:




from setup import Setup

setup = Setup()


class Verify:

    def verify(self):
        message = setup.com_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')#problem is here





error is:



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\whatever\server.py", line 11, in <module>
    verify.verify()
  File "C:\whatever\verify.py", line 9, in verify
    message = setup.com_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')#problem is here
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'recv'
```

I have not tried anything other than this, if someone could give an answer it would be very good. I will edit it if there is something missing.

Comment: This is a mishmash of problems. Do you know why your want to use classes here?

Comment: You can't "call" a class attribute by default. It has to be callable. You instantiated your class with `self.comm_socket` as an empty string, but you didn't call `make_server()` on your instance to replace that. I think you're trying to run before you can walk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to use an object inside another object the best way is to pass it in the constructor, and save it, to be later used in the methods.

```
class Verify:
    def __init__(self, setup_obj):
        self.setup_obj = setup_obj

    def verify(self):
        message = self.setup_obj.com_socket.recv(1024).decode('utf-8')  # no problem here
```

and in `server.py`

```
setup = Setup()
verify = Verify(setup)  # verify object will contain setup object and can use it.
```

Answer (score 3):

Your two modules, `server` and `verify` are each creating their own instances of the `Setup` class, both named `setup` in each module's separate global namespace. In `server`, you call `setup.make_server()` on its instance, but in `verify` you do not. That method is where the `com_socket` attribute gets fully set up, which is why `verify` doesn't find any of the expected socket methods on the string that it's `Setup` instance was initialized with.

It's rather unclear to me what your various classes are supposed to be doing. Neither `Setup` nor `Verify` is most often used as a noun, which is generally what you'd expect from a class. Perhaps you don't want classes, but top-level functions in each module that manipulate each module's global variables? Unlike Java, Python doesn't require every function to be a method (nor for each importable thing to be a class).

Alternatively, if you just want `server` and `verify` to be working with the same `setup` object, then you probably want the code to pass the object between them.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explenation, it made me understand the problem a lot better!